# selenium WebDriverWait.Untils NoSuchMethodError

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my selenium webdriver,
I am trying use WebDriverWait.Untils but it **fails** I get the error as below:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;`

My code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn-generalInfo']//span[1]"))).click();
```

my pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your xpath is wrong, i guess , can you share html element or url ?

Comment: hi @JustinLambert there is a no 'NoSuchMethodError '  its due to library not found if i understood correctly